# Group by count of distinct values within a table

Tags: sql, oracle

This is in oracle. Table EmployeeName:

```
EmployeeNameID|EmployeeID|FirstName|LastName
1|1|ABC|DEF
2|1|ABC|EFG
3|1|ABC|DEF
4|2|XYZ|PQR
5|2|DEF|RST
6|3|XYQ|BRQ
```

I want to find out how many employee records have more than one name. The result should be: First column is the EmployeeId and the 2nd column is the distinct number of names they have. For the first result the ABC|DEF repeats so I just want to count it once.

```
1|2
2|2
3|1
```

I tried to group by but not sure how to work with distinct names requirement.

Comment: "I tried"....what did you try?

Comment: Hint:  `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(FirstName,'-', LastName))
FROM EmployeeName
GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
select employeeid, count(distinct firstname || ' ' || lastname)
from t
group by employeeid;
```